# Node.js MongoDB updating document expects object, gets array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm building my first app using mongodb and node.js and I've come across a brick wall. When i try to .update() or .updateMany() my server comes back with:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): MongoError: Wrong type for 'q'. Expected a object, got a array.
```

Now the thing is, my code worked before and I have managed to insert an array of about 150 objects into my database. (When i first did this i used .insert() instead of .update(), but now neither works.)

Here's the exact code I'm using to first store an array of objects, and then .update() my database.

Store the array (I am using an external API for this):

```
  var all = [];
  $("#update").click(function(){
                          $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            dataType: 'JSON',
                            url: 'some valid url',
                              success: function (result){
                                $.each(result, function(i, item) {
                                    var obj = {
                                      "name" : item['name'],
                                      "id" : item['id'],
                                      "count" : 0
                                    };
                                    all.push(obj);
                                });
                            }
                        });
  });
```

Send to my router.js to be processed:

```
    $('#sendupdate').click(function(){
    var jsonstring = JSON.stringify(all);
    console.log(jsonstring);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "JSON",
      contentType: "application/json",
      data: jsonstring,
      url: "/s",
        success: function(response) {
          console.log('Successfully Updated');
        }
    });
  });
});
```

and finally here's what my router.js does to the received data:

```
router.post('/s', function(req, res){
  var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
  var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/someDB';
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db){
    if(err){
      console.log('unable to connect to the server', err);
    } else {
      console.log('connected');
      var collection = db.collection('someCollection');
      var data = req.body;
      console.log('data collected');
      console.log(data);
      collection.updateMany(data, data, {upsert:true});
      }
  });
});
```

Now I know I could loop through the array and make a request for each object, but that feels like I'll be using too much resources, especially knowing that I will need a similar function later on for most users that enter my site.

What else could I do to update the database with so many new objects? I understand that mongodb expects to receive an object, but I don't understand why it worked before when the data received was always an array of objects.

Thank you in advance and I hope someone can shed some light on this for me.

**________________________________________**

**EDIT:** I have come up with a temporary solution, I'm still unsure on how good it is but if anyone has any ideas on how to improve this please do let me know.

Here's what I've changed, for anyone having a similar issue:

Instead of trying to update an array with an array I've used a for loop to loop through the array[i] and update each object individually. It happens server-side and is probably not the best solution but it works for now.

Here's the changed code:

```
router.post('/s', function(req, res){
  var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
  var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/someDB';
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db){
    if(err){
      console.log('unable to connect to the server', err);
    } else {
      console.log('connected');
      var collection = db.collection('someCollection');
      var data = req.body;
      console.log('data collected');
      var i;
        for(i = 0; i <= data.length; ++i){
          collection.update(data[i], {$set:data[i]}, {upsert:true});
        }
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: data is a string ( i believe ) a d you want an Object. So may do data=JSON.parse(data); on serverside...

Comment: Just tried this out, I'm getting an error "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1" I'm guessing the format of what data receives might be wrong? data looks like [{"name": "thename"}, {"anothername": "anotherthename"}]

Comment: This error means you are trying to parse something which is already a JS object. MongoDB anyway supports bulk inserts/updates that work on arrays of documents, which data seems to be, and you call updateMany, which works on arrays. What is your problem actually?

Comment: Thanks Martin, I'm trying to find out what the problem is really. It worked to start with but now I'm getting the unhandled promise error mentioned above...

Comment: If you are using bodyparser to parse the body of post request your data will surely be object. What you should understand is if you are willing to update all the document using same criteria then you can use `updateMany()`. If not then your solution is the right solution. Can you provide the data and update you want to make? to have a clear vision here.

Comment: The problem is first parameter of the `updateMany` should be a object defining a criteria http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update